# Css not working in express with ejs template engine

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs, template-engine

i am using express js with ejs template engine
Here is my folder strcture

```
- public
----- css
---------- style.css
----- js
---------- script.js
- views
----- partials
---------- footer.ejs
---------- head.ejs
---------- header.ejs
----- pages
---------- index.ejs
---------- about.ejs
- package.json
- server.js
```

Now i want to add style css in "partials/head.js" file,how can i do this ? I tried with following codes but
not working for me,Where i am wrong ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../public/css/style.css">
```

Comment: It `should` work.. if you check in developer tools of your browser, what's the URL the browser tries to load? Do you get a 404-error?

Comment: @cloned: i am getting following error

<title>Error</title>
<pre>Cannot GET /public/css/bootstrap.css</pre>

Comment: it does not mention `public/css/bootstrap.css` in your question at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

this is your answer because in app.js you already defined the public directory from which you are serving the static files. Like css/js/image

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Try this, This is the only solution <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  otherwise <link href="/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> and don't forgot to run npm start again as well as let me know

Comment: are you installed bootstrap using npm install bootstrap ?

Comment: inside css have you added the bootstrap.css file ?

Comment: Yes , there is bootstrap.css file inside css folder

Comment: in app.js add this line app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Answer (score -1):

You tried with following codes i think working for u.

## In link give href as ../../public/css/style.css